# GridView does not allow row update or cancel when Html Endcode and Decode is used

Tags: asp.net

I am using templates in `GridView`. The columns in the `GridView` can contains special characters like for example: "<". The column data gets truncated when it tries to display the cell value with special character.
I looked up on the internet and I use `HTMLEncode` in the `ItemTemplate` and `HTMLDecode` in `EditItemTemplate`. Now, the truncation problem no longer exists. but, something really annoying happens. When I click the edit button in the row, the row goes into edit mode, and the characters appears in the decoded i.e. "<" format. Which is the right behavior. But, once this is displayed in edit mode, none of events like `rowupdate` or `rowcancel` events fire. Or in other words, clicking on Update or Cancel in the `gridview` row does nothing.

Can you please help.
P.S. I have also set the Page directive's `ValidateRequest` to false.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Have you tried setting Page's `EnableEventValidation` to false as well?